Issue with remove_action of function within function
I keep getting an Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array():
Before i put this into a class it worked totally fine.
The remove action stops an infinite loop.
What am i doing wrong here?
The below is the code.
namespace Resources;

class ResourcesSettings
{

/* Add resource to course - if its added as a block within topic but forgotten to add to course.
-----------------------------------------------------*/
public static function add_resource_to_course($post_id, $post)
{

    /*
    -----------------------------------------------------
    // PERMISSIONS
    -----------------------------------------------------
    */

    // bail out if this is an autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }

    // Check permissions
    if ('page' == $post->post_type) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
            return;
    } else {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
            return;
    }

    // If calling wp_update_post, unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely

    remove_action('save_post_sfwd-topic', [ResourcesSettings::class, 'add_resource_to_course'], 20);


    /*
    -----------------------------------------------------
    // LOGIC
    -----------------------------------------------------
    */

    // A BUNCH OF CODE HERE 

    // re-hook this function
            add_action('save_post_sfwd-topic', [ResourcesSettings::class, 'add_resource_to_course'], 20, 2);

}
}

add_action('save_post_sfwd-topic', [ResourcesSettings::class, 'add_resource_to_course'], 20, 2);

The error that is appearing each time is:
Error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "add_resource_to_course" not found or invalid function name in /home/public_html/web/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:326
Stack trace:
#0 /home/public_html/web/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#1 /home/public_html/web/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#2 /home/public_html/web/wp/wp-includes/post.php(4880): do_action()
#3 /home/public_html/web/wp/wp-includes/post.php(4993): wp_insert_post()
#4 /home/public_html/web/wp/wp-admin/includes/post.php(703): wp_update_post()
#5 /home/public_html/web/wp/wp-admin/edit.php(194): bulk_edit_posts()
#6 {main}


Can't tell from that trace, whether this is the remove_action or the add_action calls causing the error. And I'm guessing changing ResourcesSettings::class to 'ResourcesSettings' doesn't change anything either?

@C3roe the error highlights the line for the remove_action and yep ive tried that too :/

Could it be the missing namespace? Try and pass Resources\ResourcesSettings for the class name.

@C3roe Nope :( nothing

"must be a valid callback, function" - The fact that the last word in this error message is "function" and not "class", leads me to believe you might have an additional call to this somewhere else possibly? When using the array syntax it will say that either the class doesn't exist, or the class doesn't have that method.

@ChrisHaas absolutely none nowhere else. Only what you see above.

You might have to hack core then to debug this. I think I'd start at add_filter. Check for your $hook_name and then dump out all of the parameters for each call to it. If that looks as you expect, then you might have to go to the end and check out the terminal apply_filters method.

I think the easiest option here is bringing it out of the autoloaded class set and just dumping it in functions.php as a bog standard function.
